# How to rig my character's clothe

Tags: mesh, rigging, objects, weight-painting, vertex-groups

I just made a hooide for my character but I don't know how to rig it in a correct way. When I rigged the hoodie, it's always clipping to the character's body. (by the way It's blender 2.79)

I can send the blend file ıf it helps to solve the problem.

[image]

Comment: have you tried to rig it to the head bone? Yes please share your file

Comment: @moonboots Its working a bit better I guess but I think there something I'm missing. So here's the file: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5808" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5808/)

Comment: The coat is not parented to the armature

Comment: @moonboots I parented it now but there is some weight paint issues I can't fix

Comment: I can send the file again If you want

Comment: what do you mean when you say that "it's always clipping to the character's body"?

Comment: I mean this by saying that: https://imgur.com/a/calnbRo

Comment: @moonboots I tried some ways to fix that but there is still clipping like that

Comment: ok so you could either delete the mesh beneath the coat, or use a Mask modifier (maybe the best method), or use a Mesh Deform modifier as explained here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=imhTnlKrTOY
or here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P6s9H8xX7YA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you can see the body beneath the coat. The easiest method to make it invisible is to use a *Mask* modifier: Select the vertex group you want to hide, give it a name, give your object a *Mask* modifier, in the *Vertex Group* field of the modifier, select the group you've created, then use the arrow on its right to switch (<->). Now your body will be invisible.